# I want to create a html table layout in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an Html table layout using jQuery but I don't know where I am doing mistakes.

When I try to run this and check the console tab the error comes with undefined( i and table2)

I just want to show the table on the chrome page means I want the output.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function table() {
    this.column = col;
  }

  function col(value1, value2) {
    var multiply = (value1 * value2);
    return multiply;
  }
  var table2 = new table();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table border="solid 3px" style="font-size: 20px;" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <script>
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
          console.log("<th><label'>" + i + "</label></th>");
        }
      </script>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <script>
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        console.log("<tr>");
        for (var k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
          var value1 = i;
          var value2 = k;
          console.log("<td>" + table2.column(value1, value2) + "</td>");
        }
        console.log("</tr>");
      }
    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) { ` will not show `i`

Comment: i is underfied, it doesn't exist within the context of your loop.

Comment: Your *inline* script will run as it is rendered.  Your doc.ready script will run, well, when the document has finished.  You *could* move your doc.ready to an inline script before your other inline script (and remove the doc.ready wrapper), or you could move your inline scripts to your .js (the javascript box in the snippet)

Comment: Also note that `console.log` won't add html to your page.  Either `document.write` (if inline, but not recommended) or `$("table tbody").append(...` in doc.ready

Comment: `console.log` writes to the console, not to the document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simpling adding `console.log` inside a `script` tag in you required place will not add the content to the DOM. You have to manipulate the template as string and set it as the `html` content of the target using `html` method in [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Also the loop index used in the for loop was `j` and you were consoling it with `i`. The index was looping till 10. But you have only 5 columns inside a row. If that is not purposeful, you have to user loop from 1 to 5

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  maniputalteHeader();
  function table() {
    this.column = col;
  }

  function col(value1, value2) {
    var multiply = (value1 * value2);
    return multiply;
  }
  var table2 = new table();
  let template = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    template += "<tr>";
    for (var k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
      var value1 = i;
      var value2 = k;
      template += "<td>" + table2.column(value1, value2) + "</td>";
    }
    template += "</tr>";
  }
  $("#tbody").html(template);
});

function maniputalteHeader() {
  let template = '';
  for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    template += "<th><label'>" + j + "</label></th>";
  }
  $("#thead").html(template);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table border="solid 3px" style="font-size: 20px;" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr id="thead">
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
There was an i inside but it should be an j

```js
console.log("<th><label'>" + j + "</label></th>");
```

I copied your jquery code before the table2 call.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table border="solid 3px" style="font-size: 20px;" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <script>
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
          console.log("<th><label'>" + j + "</label></th>");
        }

      </script>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <script>
      function table() {
        this.column = col;
      }

      function col(value1, value2) {
        var multiply = (value1 * value2);
        return multiply;
      }
      
      var table2 = new table();
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        console.log("<tr>");
        for (var k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
          var value1 = i;
          var value2 = k;
          console.log("<td>" + table2.column(value1, value2) + "</td>");
        }
        console.log("</tr>");
      }

    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the changes.   See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. console.log does not add anything to the DOM
2. You had `i` inside a loop with `j`
3. Your head code ran to 10, the body code to 5

I think you might mean this

```js
function col(value1, value2) {
  var multiply = (value1 * value2);
  return multiply;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  const $table = $("#table1");
  const $thead = $("thead", $table)
  const $tbody = $("tbody", $table)
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $thead.append(`<th><label>${i}</label></th>`);
    const $tr = $tbody.append('<tr/>')
    for (let k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
      $tr.append($(`<td/>`, { text: col(i, k) }));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#table1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%
}

th,
td {
  border: solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To not update the DOM in every loop, push the html to an array

```js
const col = (value1, value2) => value1 * value2;
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));


$(document).ready(function() {
  const $table = $("#table1");
  const $thead = $("thead", $table);
  const $tbody = $("tbody", $table);
  const arr = range(1,5,1); // from 1 to 5 step 1
  $thead.html(arr.map(i => `<th><label>${i}</label></th>`).join(''));
  $tbody.html(arr.map(i => `<tr/>${arr.map(k => `<td>${col(i, k)}</td>`)}</tr>`).join(''))
});
```

```css
#table1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%
}

th,
td {
  border: solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues:

- `console.log` will not write to the page (the DOM), but to the console area.
- The code in the inline `script` elements will run before the code in the `ready` handler, so `table` will not be defined yet.
- Defining a constructor with the only purpose to store a function is bad practice. If this is only to do a multiplication then even a plain function is overkill.
- As you use jQuery, use it to the full, and populate the table by creating elements with jQuery instead of concatenating strings.
- Style your table with CSS classes, not with a `style` and `border` attributes. The value you gave to the `border` attribute is invalid. It accepts values "0" or "1".
- The number of cells you generated for the head-row does not correspond to the number of columns in the body of the table.

Here is corrected code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $titles = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        $titles.push($("<th>").append($("<label>").text(j)));
    }
    $("thead tr").append($titles);
    var $rows = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var $row = $("<tr>");
        for (var k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {
            $row.append($("<td>").text(i * k));
        }
        $rows.push($row);
    }
    $("tbody").append($rows);    
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Table Layout</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [No need for the push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68998587/295783) if you use jQuery all the way:

Comment: @mplungjan, of course I know that. I was doing it this way to avoid modifying the DOM in each iteration, concentrating the modification of the DOM to two actions only.

Comment: If that was your goal, see my second example ;)

Comment: We are wasting our time on this one. Asker is not interested it seems. Producing an array with like `Array.from` is of course not so much different than pushing. Both are non-jQuery, and I don't think it should be done with jQuery either.